# My phone won't boot up suddenly. Please help, thanks!

Tags: samsung, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-note-2

It is Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (GT-N7100), unrooted, stock ROM. 
It always stuck at the Samsung Galaxy Note 2 logo screen. 
I can boot to recovery mode and download mode. 
What should I do to save my phone? Thanks a lot. 
 
I tried to flash by using download mode but I got these errors.

> < ID:0/003> Added!! 
>  < ID:0/003> Odin engine v(ID:3.1205).. 
>  <
>   ID:0/003> File analysis.. 
>  < ID:0/003> SetupConnection.. 
>  <
>   ID:0/003> Initialzation.. 
>  < ID:0/003> Get PIT for mapping.. 
>   < ID:0/003> Firmware update start.. 
>  < ID:0/003> SingleDownload.
>   
>  < ID:0/003> sboot.bin 
>  < ID:0/003> FAIL! 
>  < ID:0/003> 
>   
>  < ID:0/003> Complete(Write) operation failed. 
>  < OSM> All
>   threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)

When repartition is checked,

> < ID:0/004> Added!! 
>  < ID:0/004> Odin engine v(ID:3.1205).. 
>  <
>   ID:0/004> File analysis.. 
>  < ID:0/004> SetupConnection.. 
>  <
>   ID:0/004> Initialzation.. 
>  < ID:0/004> Set PIT file.. 
>  <
>   ID:0/004> DO NOT TURN OFF TARGET!! 
>  < ID:0/004> Can't open the
>   specified file. (Line: 1831) 
>  < OSM> All threads completed.
>   (succeed 0 / failed 1)

The following errors displayed when I booted to recovery mode:

> Android system recovery < 3e > 
>  KOT49H.N7100ZSUFNL1 
>   
>   E:failed to mount /efs (No such file or directory) 
>  E:failed to
>   mount /system ((No such file or directory)) 
>   
>    # MANUAL MODE # 
>   --Appling Multi-CSC 
>  E:failed to mount /system (No such file or directory) 
>  can't mount '/system' (No such file or directory) 
>   E:failed to mount /cache (No such file or directory) 
>  can't mount
>   '/cache' (No such file or directory) 
>  E:failed to mount /cache (No
>   such file or directory) 
>  E:can't mount
>   /cache/recovery/last_recovery 
>  E:failed to mount /data (No such
>   file or directory) 
>  E:can't mount /data/log/recovery_log.txt 
>   E:failed to mount /system (No such file or directory) 
>  E:failed to
>   mount /cache (No such file or directory) 
>  E:can't mount
>   /cache/recovery/log 
>  E:can't open /cache/recovery/log 
>   E:failed to mount cache (No such file or recovery) 
>  E:Can't mount
>   /cache/recovery/last_log 
>  E:can't open /cache/recovery/last_log
>   
>  E:failed to mount /cache (No such file or recovery) 
>  E:can't
>   mount /cache/recovery/last_install 
>  E:Can't open
>   /cache/recovery/last_install 
>  E:failed to mount /cache (No such
>   file or recovery)

Comment: Those 'failed to mount' errors are disconcerting. I'm wondering if you've reached the limit of what you can do without using ODIN and getting a proper recovery installed on here. Then it may be possible to flash the stock ROM image back to the Note 2, or something newer like Resurrection Remix. You say it's not rooted, but is this running the stock ROM? Without knowing the versions of what you have installed it may be difficult to recommend a safe path from here.

Comment: Word of advice: **YOU SHOULD NEVER TICK REPARTITION-ESPECIALLY WITH NO .Pit** It's a quick-ticket to "I'm f**ked" town.

Comment: What you need to do is a attempt a reflash, and remake the partitions. As for where we can grab the .pit needed, You'll have to tell us the make and model (For example, the Samsung Tab 2 7" has 3 models-GTP3113, GTP3110 and I think GTP3100) and the advertised storage space.

Comment: It is GT-N7100. Yes it is running the stock ROM.
Any workaround or solution is fine as long as I could make it boot again. Thank you.

Comment: @DanBrown Someone told me to do so. I don't know it is dangerous. It is GT-N7100, running stock ROM. What should I do? I believe it is 16GB. How could I check when it won't even boot up?

Comment: That's enough info, I think. I'll see if I can find a .pit for you :) Checking repartition should only be done if the partitions are damaged and you have a .pit file to flash. The partitions don't often take damage, and the results of damage can get... Interesting.

Comment: Alright, So here is what I found:   You can attempt to reflash the stock ROM via ODIN, which is a results may vary, but usually works. Just leave repartition off. Alternatively (or if that don't work) there is a pit file for you, [thanks XDA,](https://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=1575322&d=1355893688) install the ODIN stock ROM again, this time with the .pit selected (and repartition ticked) Let me know if it works, And I'll draft an answer for you to tick (to help others with future, related issues)

Comment: I used this [firmware](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/download/28988/N7100XXUFND3_N7100ODDFND2_INU/) to flash using ODIN but failed. Did I use the right firmware? The error messages were given above. Only "Auto Reboot" and "F. Reset Time" are checked the first time I tried. Then I checked "Re-Partition" too the second time.

Comment: What country are you from??

Comment: @DanBrown Hong Kong

Comment: Ah, and where did you get the phone from? You've got an India Stock here.

Comment: @DanBrown Same place. I just searched on the net and got one which seemed to fit my model. What's the difference among ROMs of different countries? Does it really matter?

Comment: I don't really know the difference, other than matching them right gives a lower chance of Odin being a meano and voiding Knox (which essentially kicks any warranty or official support into orbit) Though since it's official, it shouldn't happen.

Comment: Under odin there is option to copy PIT partition information table. adb shell command is
dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 of=/sdcard/out.pit bs=8 count=580 skip=2176. Pit is different for different storage and different country mobile.